# Windows 7 Ultimate DVD for other editions

Tags: windows-7, windows, dvd

Assuming I am accounting for 32-bit and 64-bit DVDs, can I use a Windows 7 Ultimate DVD for lower editions of Windows 7 (E.G: Home Basic, Pro, etc...)? I kind of answered my question on this as it seemed to have worked but I wanted to know if the DVDs that come with other editions are the exact same. I want to mention that these are retail DVDs and not ones that come from a manufacturer.

Also, is the same thing true for Windows Vista DVDs. I assume that the same is not true for Windows XP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The ISO of the Windows Versions are same.
2. Whether Ultimate or Professional or Home Premium the ISO size is also same.
3. There is `ei.cfg` file labels it as Home Premium, Ultimate etc.
4. If this file exist on the ISO it will not give you the option to choose which version you want to install.
5. If you delete the file from the ISO, it will allow you to install which ever version you want provided you have a Product Key for that version.

I am attaching a screenshot from my Bizspark account to show you that the ISO sizes are same.
[image: Comparing Sizes]

Comment: Thank you. Can you say the same is true for Windows Vista? XP?

Comment: Its true for Vista, but i think NOT for XP .. this is as far as my knowledge goes ..